# Can't connect to AVD in Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run AVD using Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins, but after running emulator it can't connect to device:

```
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -no-boot-anim -ports 5829,5830 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_160_WVGA_android-19_armeabi-v7a_myapp -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window -force-32bit
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Failed to open libEGL_translator
Failed to init_egl_dispatch
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed!
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized!
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed

$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb connect emulator-5829
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5829 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device not found
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5829 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
error: device offline
```

Comment: Are you certain that the $ adb connect emulator-5829 is really starting the emulator? This might not be a "Jenkins can't connect" issue, it might be a "the emulator isn't starting" issue.

Comment: I think `adb` should just connect to already started emulator. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: You're right about that. I misspoke in the first comment. The essence of it is still applicable though...are you sure the emulator has started on your build machine?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: The emulator is starting, but adb isn't connecting to it. Are you running on OS X? The next release of the plugin should hopefully make this more reliable. In the meantime you can try deleting the emulator (from ~/.android/avd). You should also try an x86 instead of ARM emulator as it's much faster.

Comment: Now I can only say that it happens from time to time, not always. So I can't figure out what might be the problem... @ChristopherOrr, I looked into `avd` folder, it's clean.

Comment: btw, I'm running it on ubuntu 14.04 VM. And I can't run x86 at all: `emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!`

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11952 I have the same thing

Comment: Yeah, that's the bug. If the ~/.android/avd/ folder is clean, you presumably have the "create emulator in workspace" global config option enabled. In which case, you can try deleting the workspace, or the `.android/` directory there. BTW, are you on Mac OS X?